# Safari 11: how to get videos to autoplay when they don't have sound

Tags: html, video, safari, hubspot

We are adding a new page to our site that has information videos embedded into it similar to how Apple has on their own home page. I know Safari 11 blocks videos from autoplaying but I believe this is only if they have a soundtrack which ours don't. We have exported the videos without the soundtrack but for some reason, they just will not autoplay on Safari 11 but will on other browsers (and older versions of Safari). I have tried adding in the `muted` attribute as well.

Appreciate any guidance here. I don't know whether this is a HubSpot thing, or if Safari really thinks this is the sort of video it should block from autoplay.

Here is a link to a video:

https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/2619113/Videos/Sign-in.mp4

Here is a link to the preview page of the site (our site is hosted by HubSpot so this is within that platform).

http://www.chekrite.com/features?hs_preview=lOjghGJT-5375973694

Here is the code that we are using to display the video:

```
<div class="image-checks add-right-fade fw-animated-element">
    <video width="100%" loop muted autoplay="autoplay">
        <source src="{{ widget.video }}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't repro on Safari 11.0 on osx 10.12.6. [Your video autoplays fine](https://jsfiddle.net/hqs12ujL/) even though the player doesn't show it doesn't have a sound track...

Comment: I'm on Safari 11.0 on OSX 10.13. Would the OS make a difference?

Comment: Yes probably it will. Not sure which version has the final behavior.

Comment: Yeah - It's definitely not working for me on 10.13 (High Sierra) so perhaps it's the combination of Safari 11 and High Sierra that has implemented this restriction.